# How to enter 64-bit mode on a x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, bare-metal

I've found a nice bit of assembly in xv6 https://github.com/chrisdew/xv6/blob/master/bootasm.S which shows me how to move from 16 bit to 32 bit protected mode.

Does anyone know of a similar example for entering the 64-bit mode?  (Either through or without using 32 bit mode.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to enable 64 bit capabillities, you must switch the CPU to Long Mode.

To enter Long Mode on a 64-bit x86 processor (x86-64):

```
If paging is enabled, disable paging.
If CR4.PAE is not already set, set it.
Set IA32_EFER.LME = 1.
Load CR3 with a valid PML4 table.
Enable paging.
At this point you will be in compatibility mode. A far jump may be executed to switch to long mode. However, the offset must not exceed 32-bit.
```

Comment: Official documentation: [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3A: System Programming Guide:](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html) "Section 9.8.5 Initializing IA-32e Mode"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go directly to 64-bit mode, you can do something like this:

```
%xdefine PML4_BASE  0x70000     ; Address of PML4-table.
%xdefine CR0_PE     1 << 0
%xdefine CR0_PG     1 << 31
%xdefine CR4_PAE    1 << 5
%xdefine CR4_PGE    1 << 7
%xdefine EFER_LME   1 << 8

mov  eax, CR4_PAE | CR4_PGE     ; Set PAE- (Physical Address Extensions) and
mov  cr4, eax                   ;   PGE- (Page Global Enable).
mov  eax, PML4_BASE             ; Address of PML4.
mov  cr3, eax                   ; Point CR3 to PML4.
mov  ecx, 0xC0000080            ; EFER MSR selector.
rdmsr                           ; Read from model specific register.
or   eax, EFER_LME              ; Set LME (Long Mode Enable).
wrmsr                           ; Write to model specific register.
mov  ebx, cr0                   ; Get CR0.
or   ebx, CR0_PG | CR0_PE       ; Set PG (Paging) and PE (Protection Enabled).
mov  cr0, ebx                   ; Set flags to CR0.
lgdt [GDT.ptr]                  ; Load global descriptor table.
jmp  GDT.code_0:long_mode_entry ; Jump to long mode.
```

Above code requires that you have already setup page tables and Global Descriptor Table.

Answer (score 1):

[OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) is a good resource for low-level info on x86 (and a bit on other architectures). For example, [this article](http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Stephanvanschaik/Setting_Up_Long_Mode) is a pretty good writeup on the Long mode and how to enter it, both from protected mode and directly from real mode:

> ## Entering Long Mode
>
> Entering long mode can be both done from real mode and protected mode,
> however only protected mode is covered in the Intel and AMD64 manuals.
> Early AMD documentation explains this process works from real mode as
> well.