# Switch to 32bit mode from 64bit mode on intel 64

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

Is there any way to switch to 32-bit mode (legacy mode) from 64-bit mode(long mode) on a Intel 64 machine.
what are the control register configurations needed to do this using assembly code?

I need to do this in a 64bit uefi shell app

Comment: In what environment are you executing? Obviously you can't do this from ring 3 with a running OS.

Comment: Actual legacy mode or just the compatibility sub-mode of long mode?

Comment: I want to switch to legacy mode not  compatibility mode I'm trying to change the processor mode from a 64-bit uefi shell application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962251/how-to-enter-64-bit-mode-on-a-x86-64#comment35060419_22962251

Comment: I need to switch from 64-bit to 32-bit,not 32-bit to 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

I think the procedure is

1. Make sure your code is identity-mapped
2. Switch to compatibility mode
3. Disable paging (you are now in 32bit PMode with no paging)
4. Set things up however you want (for ex. clear CR4.PAE, clear EFER.LME, enable paging again)

Attempting to clear CR4.PAE from either sub-mode of long mode will #GP.